# Running two node servers with one bash script and receive console logs

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a bash script:

```
node web/dist/web/src/app.js & node api/dist/api/src/app.js &

$SHELL
```

It successfully starts both my node servers. However:

1. I do not receive any output (from console.log etc) in my terminal window
2. If I cancel by (Ctrl +C) the processes are not exited, so then I annoyingly have to manually do a taskkill /F /PID etc afterwards.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't stop your background jobs with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is because signals (`SIGINT` in this case) are received only by the foreground process.

When your foreground process (the *non-interactive* main script) exits, its children processes become [orphans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) which are immediately adopted by the `init` process. To kill them, you need their PIDs. (When you run a background process in *an interactive shell*, it will receive the `SIGHUP`, and probably exit, when shell exits.)

The solution in your case is to make your script **wait for its children**, using the shell built-in `wait` command. `wait` will ensure your script receives the `SIGINT`, which you can then handle (with `trap`) and kill the background jobs (with `kill 0`):

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill 0' EXIT

node app1.js &
node app2.js &

wait
```

By setting `trap` on `EXIT` (special pseudo-signal in `bash`), you'll ensure background processes will terminate *whenever* your main script exits (either by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/`SIGINT`, or by any other signal like `SIGTERM`, `SIGHUP`, `SIGKILL`). The `kill 0` command kills all processes in the current process group.

---

Regarding the output -- on Linux, background processes will inherit the standard output/error from shell (if not redirected), and continue to write to your TTY/terminal. If that's not working on Windows, I'm not sure why not.

However, even if your background processes somehow lost their way to your TTY, you can, as a workaround, append to a log file:

```
node app1.js >>/path/to/file.log 2>&1 &
node app2.js >>/path/to/file.log 2>&1 &
```

and then `tail -f` that log file, either in this, or some other terminal:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic comment and explanation. Ctrl+C still doesn't seem to work for me. But it's not a big deal, closing the shell, seems to kill all background processes. Do you have any idea how I can ensure any logged messages from node scripts are output to my shell ? (I'm also running this Window, unsure if that is causing an issue?)

Comment: Yes, this could be a Windows thing. On Linux, output continues to go the TTY, and `wait` handles `Ctrl+C`. As a workaround, you could log the output to a file, and then `tail -f` from that file. Let me add that option to the answer.